# How distinguish different JMS text messages from the same queue?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have an AMQ queue I'm connecting to. The publisher is sending JMS TextMessage. The messages are of different types: foo-updated, bar-updated, baz-updated etc, all on the single queue.

The payload/message body is JSON for all types, and their schemas have significant overlap (but no direct type information).

The publishing team said "search the string/text of the message for foo, and if it's there, it's a foo-updated message".

That sounds wrong.

There may be header information in the JMS message I can use (I'm exploring that), but assuming I can influence (but not necessarily change anything), what's the best way to handle this ?

Comment: Do you need to process only a specific type of message? If not, what's stopping you from getting a message from the queue, looking at the body for the type information, and then processing the message accordingly? It's not clear from your question if/why you need to distinguish one type of message from another.

Comment: Sorry for missing that detail: Yes, I'm only interested in foo messages, and want to ignore bar and baz messages (and ignore them with the least amount of processing, because I expect this to be a high traffic topic/queue).

Comment: How do you distinguish between the actual types? Is there a JSON field that disambiguates them? If there is, you could use JSON Path (example here https://cassiomolin.com/2016/07/13/using-jackson-and-json-path-to-query-and-parse-an-arbitrary-json-node/) to go find that specific node, rather than doing a hit-or-miss String search (which could lead to bad type determination if the text "foo" appears in a "baz-updated" message, for example).

Answer (score 1):

If you have influence over using JMS topics, you should use that. Just like REST URLs you could use topics to indicate resources and actions on those: foo/create, foo/update, bar/update 
Then the JMS Broker can help you to efficiently route different messages to difference consumers. E.g. one consumer subscribing to `foo/*` another to `*/update`

If you are stuck with a queue, the publisher should add additional information as header properties, for example type=foo and action=update. Then your consumer can specify JMS selectors like "action = 'update'" to receive only some of the messages.

Otherwise you are actually stuck with looking into the content :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use JMS Message Selectors
See: [Message Selectors](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-message-service/0596000685/ch03s03.html)

Comment: Good idea, but I should have added the producer team (that owns the queue) said "no selectors"  (I asked about using selectors for other reasons, and was told no, all filtering must be done by me, the client/consumer)

Comment: For what it's worth, selectors only work on headers/properties (i.e. not on the message body), and the question says there *may* be header information so selectors aren't necessarily viable.